# Можно ли использовать несколько макетов для одного arrayadapter?

Tags: android

У меня есть список, мне надо его отобразить.
Могу ли я сделать так, чтобы у одних элементов отображался текст и картинка, а у других только текст? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: да, можете так сделать. чтобы получить более полезный ответ приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример вашей проблемы

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не указали на базе чего строится ваш список, но вообще можно так сделать конечно. Суть в том если вы используете `RecyclerView` то у вас каждый элемент имеет свою разметку которую можно настроить по вашему усмотрению. А дальше все просто - вы передаете в адаптер позицию элемента у которого должен быть только текст и отображаете только текст, при это скрывая виджет для картинки (`ImageView`). Если же вы не используете `RecyclerView` а `ListView` то я бы вам советовал посмотреть в сторону данного виджета. Так же можно сделать то что вы хотите и при помощи `ListView`. В адаптере данного виджета нужно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                        break;
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }
```

и дальше уже все тоже просто. Но на мой взгляд делать кучу layout-ов для разных элементов списка как-то не очень рационально. Проще и логичнее просто скрывать/показывать нужные вам части и все. Вот [туториал](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) для `ListView` где более подробно объясняется то что я привел в данном ответе, а [вот](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b) для `RecyclerView`.